# What is wrong with my angular-module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one simple angularJS module: angular-deck. It's module for work with a game deck. Not production, beta =)

So... And I have one problem which I can't decide. Game cards by default is a simple svg images, and again by default all cards auto-loaded in the starting module work phase. When needed to insert some concrete card programmer do it like:

```
<card data-velue="'2H'">
```

And suggest directive simple insert the needed svg card through jquery:

```
$(element).html('');
__deck__[card].clone().appendTo(element);
```

But in fact the svg loading again, instead of the cloning svg from `__deck[card]__` array. There is a problem.

Tested in google-chrome.

Sourse:

[github: angular-deck](https://github.com/Aleksey-Danchin/angular-deck)

[directive: card.directive.js](https://github.com/Aleksey-Danchin/angular-deck/blob/master/source/src/directives/card.directive.js)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of cloning, try to make a copy with `angular.copy(__deck__[card])` I think if it's a perfect clone, all the binding to that element are the same.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I decided it's problem. I use CSS. I create the dinamic styles with many background values.